# (AS3) Gathering data from fitbit api

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fitbit

I'm trying to setup a mini game using the fitbit API.  I need to grab some of the user(s) data for game manip.  I'm not 100% how I would access them.  This is my current attempt but doesn't work.  I was trying to follow this thread https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fitbit-api/n0yv3-dzAqY/8y6old2EItQJ.  If I'm way off or there is a better idea, please let me know.  This is getting to unknown territory.  After I get this working and will post finished app.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

import org.iotashan.oauth.IOAuthSignatureMethod;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthConsumer;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthRequest;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthToken;

public class Fitbit extends Sprite
{

    private static var CONSUMER_SECRET:String = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    private static var CONSUMER_KEY:String = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    private static var REQUEST_TOKEN_URL:String = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token";
    //private static var REQUEST_TOKEN_URL:String = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=";
    private static var ACCESS_TOKEN_URL:String = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static var AUTHORIZE_URL:String = "http://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize";
    private static var API_URL:String = "http://api.fitbit.com";
    private static var SIGNATURE:IOAuthSignatureMethod = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();

    public function Fitbit()
    {
        var consumer:OAuthConsumer = new OAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
        var token:OAuthToken = new OAuthToken(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
        var mainRequest:OAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest(URLRequestMethod.GET,API_URL+'/1/user/2FV43Z/profile.json',null,consumer,token);
        var getDataHead:URLRequestHeader = mainRequest.buildRequest(SIGNATURE, "header", API_URL);
        var getDataURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(API_URL+'/1/user/2FV43Z/profile.json');
        getDataURL.requestHeaders.push(getDataHead);
        var getDataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        getDataLoader.load(getDataURL);
        getDataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadComplete);
        getDataLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError); 
    }

    public function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace(e.currentTarget.data);
        1+1;
    }

    public function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
        trace("FINISHED");
        1+1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? You need to elaborate. Are you seeing any errors? Does your onLoadComplete function execute?

Comment: Sorry I should of waited before making this post.  I was just so flustered.

Comment: My biggest issue is I never did oauth before, so I don't know exactly where to start and if I'm even doing this right.  I found some code and tried to adapt it to my needs.  Not 100% on what everything mean though.  After some research I think I need to request the token and gather the response.  I edited my previous code to show some updates.


I hit onError with the following message 

{"errors":[{"errorType":"oauth","fieldName":"n/a","message":"No Authorization header provided in the request. Each call to Fitbit API should be OAuth signed"}],"success":false}